# How do I install Filezilla server?

Tags: installation, 11.04, filezilla

I'm trying to get Filezilla FTP server and install it, but I can't find out how to. Can anyone help?

Comment: As stated, FileZilla server is only for Windows. If you want an FTP server on your Ubuntu server you may want to look into [vsftpd](http://www.jonathanmoeller.com/screed/?p=2981)

Comment: You can try a FTP server setup on Ubuntu. Here is a link to learning how to setup an FTP server: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/ftp-server.html

Comment: Any reason to use Filezilla FTP server implementation specifically? There's loads of other implementations in Ubuntu's repositories.

Comment: https://filezilla-project.org/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The FileZilla server is a Windows only program.

Comment: @Robert You can try to run FileZilla server using Wine (see [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine) for a short introduction to Wine), but if I were you I'd try to look for an alternative supported by Ubuntu (I don't know one, maybe make this another question). If my answer answered your question, you can click on the check mark next to it to mark it as accepted (that's how we say "thanks" at Ask Ubuntu :-)).

Answer (score 1):

You can try wine, I tried it and it said to it needed a higher version of windows. To fix this go to `Configure Wine` and click `Add Application` then select Fillezilla installation program (Server) and in Windows Version select Windows Vista or higher. You can choose. I picked Windows 7.